# Somar chaves específicas obtidas em consulta SQL - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma consulta sql que retorna todos os campos de uma tabela :

```
$registro = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM agenda ORDER BY procedimento LIMIT $limit, $nroLotes");
```

Minha dúvida é, se é possível, através dessa consulta, somar os valores de determinada coluna, associados aos valores de outra coluna, ex:

Dentre outras colunas existem "Coluna : Nome" onde os valores são nomes e "Coluna : Valor" onde os valores são números. A idéia é somar os valores associados aos nomes.

Imagino que devo fazer um foreach dentro do while, mas estou com dificuldade nessa abordagem.

Segue o trecho do código em questão:

```
<?php
//...
$registro = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM agenda ORDER BY procedimento     LIMIT $limit, $nroLotes");
$tabela = $tabela.'<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-  hover">
                    <tr>
                  <th width="300">Nome</th>
                  <th width="200">Procedimentos</th>
                  <th width="150">Valor Cobrado do serviço</th>
                  <th width="150">Valor Total dos serviços</th>
                  <th width="150">Porcentagem do Valor Total dos serviços</th>
                  <th width="150">Data</th>
                    </tr>';


while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($registro)){
$porcentagem = ($linha['valor'] * 30) / 100;
$tabela = $tabela.'<tr>
                        <td>'.$linha['nome_funcionario'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$linha['procedimento'].'</td>
                        <td>'.number_format($linha['valor'], 2, ',', '.').'</td>
                        <td>'.number_format($porcentagem).'</td>
                        //célula que conterá a soma 
                        //<td>'.number_format($soma).'</td>
                        <td>'.fechaNormal($linha['start']).'</td>';     
}
$tabela = $tabela.'</table>';

$array = array(0 => $tabela,
               1 => $lista);

echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posso estar enganado, mas você pode conseguir isso no próprio SQL usando `SUM()` e `GROUP BY`.

Tente rodar a seguinte Query na sua tabela (verifique os nomes dos campos se estão certos):

`SELECT *, SUM('valor') AS SomaValor FROM agenda GROUP BY 'nome' ORDER BY procedimento`

Veja se o resultado de `SomaValor` é o que você está procurando.

Comment: No caso eu teria que colocar : $linha['SomaValor']?

Comment: @MagicHat sim, só confira se a Query está certa, pois eu não tive tempo de testá-la, então não tenho certeza.